# Cannot install node.js - oracle module on Windows 7

Tags: node.js, oracle

https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracle

this is document Guide.

I followed it word for word.

and cmd.exe -> go to project place -> `npm install oracle` isn't working.

I also used the `mssql` module, it's perfectly working.

this is error message:

```
npm ERR! oracle@0.3.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the oracle@0.3.7 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the oracle package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls oracle
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "oracle"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\user\Desktop\WBPWebService
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: There's an open issue about it: https://github.com/joeferner/node-oracle/issues/205

Comment: @generalhenry that's ubuntu issues, not Windows.

Comment: that one not so much there are a number of others having the same types of issues.  It's all variations on the cpp not building https://github.com/joeferner/node-oracle/search?q=windows&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: There are instructions in the readme